# SQL Code working in SSMS but not in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms, reportbuilder3.0

I have a code that works in SSMS but not in Report Builder. Tn the first part I create a temporary table and in the second i attach that table (using join) to my entire query. In SSMS i can do it declaring twice the parameters and using GO after the temporary table is created but RP Builder i cannot use go. 
Below you can find the code.

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempResTable') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #TempResTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp123') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #Temp123

declare @fromDate date
set @fromDate='2015-10-26'
declare @toDate date
set @toDate='2015-11-17'

    Create table #tempResTable (id_resource int, Mins int)
    while (@fromDate <= @toDate)
    begin 
    Insert into #TempResTable 
        select
        r.id_resource
        ,datediff(mi,coalesce(cw.from_time,convert(time, '12:00:00 AM')),coalesce(cw.till_time,convert(time , '23:59:59 PM')))  as 'MinutesAvailable'
        from calendar
        join resource r on r.id_calendar=calendar.id_calendar
        left join calendarVersion cv on cv.id_calendarVersion=calendar.id_calendar
        left join calendarweekdayentry cw on cw.id_calendarVersion=cv.id_calendarVersion  
        --where r.id_resource=@resource 
        where cw.id_availabilitykind in(2,8)
        and cw.weekday=(case when (datediff(dd,cv.from_date,@fromDate)+1)-((datediff(dd,cv.from_date,@fromDate)+1)/(nofweeks*7)*(nofweeks*7))=0 then nofweeks*7
                        else (datediff(dd,cv.from_date,@fromDate)+1)-((datediff(dd,cv.from_date,@fromDate)+1)/(nofweeks*7)*(nofweeks*7))
                        end)
        Group By r.id_resource
        ,cv.from_date
        ,cw.from_time
        ,cw.till_time,cw.id_availabilitykind
        --)  

        set @fromDate=dateadd(dd,1,@fromDate)
    end
go
declare @fromDate date
set @fromDate='2015-10-26'
declare @toDate date
set @toDate='2015-11-17'


select * into #temp123 from
(
select vwdepartment.departmentName 
 ,row_number() over (order by resource.ID_resource) as 'rowNumber'
,resource.resourceName
,resource.id_resource
,B.AvailabilityHours
--,vwplannedShift.id_shift
--,vwplannedShift.plannedstartinstant
--,vwplannedShift.plannedfinishinstant 
--,datediff(mi,vwplannedShift.plannedstartinstant,vwplannedShift.plannedfinishinstant)
, ( select  sum(distinct(datediff(mi,vwplannedShift.plannedstartinstant,vwplannedShift.plannedfinishinstant))) from resource r1 where r1.resourceName=resource.resourceName group by r1.resourceName   ) as 'MinsPlanned'
--,cw.from_time
--,cw.till_time
--,[dbo].[sp_ResourceAvailability]
from vwplannedShift
join vwshift on vwshift.id_shift = vwplannedShift.id_shift
and datediff(dd,@fromDate , vwplannedShift.plannedStartInstant) >=0
and datediff(dd,@toDate , vwplannedShift.plannedStartInstant) <=0
join vwdepartment on vwdepartment.id_department = vwplannedShift.id_department
join vwaction actions on coalesce(actions.t3_shift, actions.id_shift) = vwshift.id_shift 
join vwresourceCombinationDriver driver on actions.id_unionResourceCombi = driver.id_resourceCombination                        
join resource on driver.id_resource = resource.id_resource  
join resourceKind rk on rk.id_resourceKind=resource.id_resourceKind
join calendar c on c.id_calendar=resource.id_calendar
join calendarversion cv on cv.id_calendar=c.id_calendar
join calendarweekdayentry cw on cw.id_calendarVersion=cv.id_calendarVersion
left join availabilityKind ak on ak.id_availabilityKind=cw.id_availabilityKind and cw.id_availabilityKind in (2,8)
LEFT JOIN (select id_resource, sum(mins)AS AvailabilityHours from #tempResTable GROUP BY #tempResTable.id_resource) B ON B.ID_RESOURCE=RESOURCE.ID_RESOURCE
group by resource.resourcename,resource.id_resource,vwdepartment.departmentName,B.AvailabilityHours

union

select vwdepartment.departmentName 
 ,row_number() over (order by resource.ID_resource) as 'rowNumber'
 ,resource.resourceName
,resource.id_resource
,B.AvailabilityHours
--,vwplannedShift.id_shift
--,vwplannedShift.plannedstartinstant
--,vwplannedShift.plannedfinishinstant
--,datediff(mi,vwplannedShift.plannedstartinstant,vwplannedShift.plannedfinishinstant) 
,( select sum(distinct(datediff(mi,vwplannedShift.plannedstartinstant,vwplannedShift.plannedfinishinstant))) from resource r1 where r1.resourceName=resource.resourceName group by r1.resourceName    ) as 'MinsPlanned'
--,cw.from_time
--,cw.till_time
from vwplannedShift
join vwshift on vwshift.id_shift = vwplannedShift.id_shift
and datediff(dd,@fromdate , vwplannedShift.plannedStartInstant) >=0
and datediff(dd,@todate , vwplannedShift.plannedStartInstant) <=0
join vwdepartment on vwdepartment.id_department = vwplannedShift.id_department
join vwaction actions on coalesce(actions.t3_shift, actions.id_shift) = vwshift.id_shift 
join vwresourcecombinationtruck truck on actions.id_unionResourceCombi = truck.id_resourceCombination
join resource on truck.id_resource = resource.id_resource
join resourceKind rk on rk.id_resourceKind=resource.id_resourceKind
left join calendar c on c.id_calendar=resource.id_calendar
left join calendarversion cv on cv.id_calendar=c.id_calendar
left join calendarweekdayentry cw on cw.id_calendarVersion=cv.id_calendarVersion
left join availabilityKind ak on ak.id_availabilityKind=cw.id_availabilityKind and cw.id_availabilityKind in (2,8)
LEFT JOIN (select id_resource, sum(mins)AS AvailabilityHours from #tempResTable GROUP BY #tempResTable.id_resource) B ON B.ID_RESOURCE=RESOURCE.ID_RESOURCE
group by resource.resourcename,resource.id_resource,vwdepartment.departmentName,B.AvailabilityHours
) as cte


select* from #temp123
```

Comment: What if you try `declare @tempResTable table(id_resource int, Mins int)` instead?

Comment: Explain to us why you think you need the `GO` in your script in the Report Builder...

Comment: Because without Go after the first part and new declaration of parameters, my query won't work.

Comment: Why not simply reset the variables? There's no reason to declare them again...

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [documentation on GO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

So not recognized by Report Builder.

Answer (score 0):

While [TT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061903/2311633) has identified the problem with the code you have, the workaround would be to create a new Stored Procedure in the database, which will allow you to create, populate and interrogate temporary tables at will.

Something like this perhaps?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMyData] ( @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATEIME )

    Create table #tempResTable (id_resource int, Mins int)
    ...
    (All the rest of your code (without the variable declarations and 'GOs')
    ...
    select* from #temp123
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[GetMyData] TO [MyUser]
GO
```

Then reference this directly from your Dataset by choosing "Stored Procedure" instead of "Text"